# Why do I get the error "Unrecognized selector sent to instance error"

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I'm just learning Objective C and have come across this issue. I have created a simple manager class like so

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PassManager : NSObject

- (void)isValidCredentials:(NSString *) username
          withPassword:(NSString *) password
              wasValid:(void(^)(BOOL success))handler;

@end
```

the implementation is as follows

```
#import "PassManager.h"

@implementation PassManager

- (void)isValidCredentials:(NSString *) username
          withPassword:(NSString *) password
              wasValid:(void(^)(BOOL success))handler
{
    handler(true); 
}

@end
```

This builds but upon running I get the error:

> "2016-01-27 16:40:41.555 MessyApp[19395:897750] -[PassManager initWithConfiguration:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd12a413d30 2016-01-27 16:40:41.560 MessyApp[19395:897750] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PassManager initWithConfiguration:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd12a413d30'".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Update your question with the complete and exact error message. 2. Point out which line of code is causing the error.

Comment: you should always check that a block isn't `nil` before calling it. The error you're getting is for something else though.

Comment: 2016-01-27 16:40:41.555 MessyApp[19395:897750] -[PassManager initWithConfiguration:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd12a413d30
2016-01-27 16:40:41.560 MessyApp[19395:897750] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PassManager initWithConfiguration:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd12a413d30'

Comment: @John Please update OP with this. People shouldn't be expected to dig through the comments to find the description of the problem.

Comment: At the minute I have not even attempted to call it. Its when the app starts running in the simulator

Comment: well the code you've included isn't where the problem is. Please update OP with the relevant bit of code (somewhere you are calling `initWithConfiguration` on `PassManager`, which doesn't respond to that method).

Comment: The initWithConfiguration method is not something I wrote I was assuming its in the NSObject that the PassManager is derived from. What I have provided is the complete .h and .m as I see in the editor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101801/discussion-between-originaluser2-and-john).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking to originaluser2 he showed me it was something else causing the problem. I was using a library called Parse that required startup code in the appdelegate class and it was that what was blowing up. Once he showed me that I looked at what else I did and realised I had created a class called ParseManager that was causing some sort of name conflict. I changed this classes name and sure enough it all started working. Bad question on my part I'm afraid but Im a new to this platform

Answer (score 0):

Well the error says it all, somewhere in your code you are calling the `initWithConfiguration` method on an `PassManager` but you don't have that method in your `PassManager` class, so it throws an exception.

Either add the method and implement it in your `PassManager` class, or if you want to catch exactly where this is happening (and don't want to search for all the occurrences of `initWithConfiguration`.

You could go to `Breakpoint Navigator` by pressing `CMD+7` and then on the bottom press the `+` sign and add an `Exception Breakpoint`, run the app and wait for it to fire.

Good luck.

Comment: OP found the answer to his question, it was down to class naming conflict with the Parse API.